# Velocity Custom Field if null skip

Tags: jira, velocity, jira-plugin

I've created a PDF Export for JIRA in velocity (using the PDF View extension).

It's all gone quite smoothly, however in one of my templates, I want to skip inserting data if the Custom Field is null:

```
#foreach($issue in $issues)                            
<fo:table-row>
    <fo:table-cell border="thin solid #000" padding="0.5em" number-columns-spanned="2">
        #set($value = $xmlutils.escape($issue.key))
        <fo:block>$value</fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-cell border="thin solid #000" padding="0.5em" number-columns-spanned="5">
        #set($customField = $customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObject("customfield_10008"))
        <fo:block>#cfValue($customField)</fo:block> 
    </fo:table-cell>                                                                   
</fo:table-row>
```

So basically I want to check if the Custom Field is null, and if so, skip adding the item to the table.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use getCustomfieldObject method, you get a representation of that Customfield in general, not the value for a specific issue.

You can use :

```
customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObject("customfield_10008").getValue(issue)
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks for your help, though I had to change it slightly: `#set($value2 = $customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObject("customfield_10008").getValue($issue))`